# Best SQL indexes for join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, indexing, rails-migrations

With performance improvements in mind, I was wondering if and which indexes are helpful on a join table (specifically used in a Rails 3 has_and_belongs_to_many context).

### Model and Table Setup

My models are `Foo` and `Bar` and per rails convention, I have a join table called `bars_foos`. There is no primary key or timestamps making the old fields in this table `bar_id:integer` and `foo_id:integer`. I'm interested in knowing which of the following indexes is best and is without duplication:

1. A compound index: `add_index :bars_foos, [:bar_id, :foo_id]`
2. - Two indexes
   - A. `add_index :bars_foos, :bar_id`
   - B. `add_index :bars_foos, :foo_id`
3. A combination of both 1 and 2-B

Basically, I'm not sure if the compound index is enough assuming it is helpful to begin with. I believe that a compound index can be used as a single index for the first item which is why I am *pretty* sure that using all three lines would certainly result in unnecessary duplication.

### Likely Usage

The most common usage will be given an instance of model `Foo`, I will be asking for its associated `bars` using the RoR syntax of `foo.bars` and vice versa with `bar.foos` for an instance of the model `Bar`.

These will generate queries of the type `SELECT * FROM bars_foos WHERE foo_id = ?` and `SELECT * FROM bars_foos WHERE bar_id = ?` respectively and then using those resultant IDs to `SELECT * FROM bars WHERE ID in (?)` and `SELECT * FROM foos WHERE ID in (?)`.

Please correct me in the comments if I am incorrect, but I do not believe that, in the context of the Rails application, it is ever going to try to do a query where it specifies both IDs like `SELECT * FROM bars_foos where bar_id = ? AND foo_id = ?`.

### Databases

In the event there are database specific optimization techniques, I will most likely be using PostgreSQL. However, others using this code may want to use it in MySQL or SQLite depending on their Rails configuration so all answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## The Answer

The oft repeated answer, which tends to always be the case more often than not is, "it depends." More specifically, it depends on what your data is and how it will be used.

## tl;dr Explanation

The short tl;dr answer for my specific case (and to cover all future bases) is **choice #2** which is what I suspected. However, choice #3 would work just fine as, depending on my usage of the data, the extra time and space used creating the compound index could reduce future query lookups.

## The Full Explanation

The reason for this is that databases try to be smart and try to do things as fast as possible regardless of programmer input. The most basic item to consider when adding an index is will this object be looked up by this key. If yes, an index can potentially help speed that up. However, whether this index is even used all comes down to selectivity and the cardinality of the field.

Since foreign keys are typically the IDs of another AR class, cardinality usually will be high. But again, this depends on your data. In my example if there are many `Foo`s but few `Bar`s, many of the entries in my join table will have simliar `bar_id`s. With `bar_id`s having a low cardinality, an index on `bar_id` may never be used and may be getting in the way by having the database devote time and resources* to adding to this index every time a new `bars_foos` entry is created. The same goes with many `Bar`s and few `Foo`s and few of both.

The general lesson is that when considering an index on a table, decide if the entries will be both looked up by this field and if this field has a high cardinality. That is, does this field have many distinct values? In the case of most join tables "it depends" and we must think more carefully about what the data represents and the relationships themselves. In my case, I will have *both* many `Foo`s and `Bar`s and will be looking up `Foo`s by their associated `bar`s and vice versa.

Another good answer I got at the office was, "why are you worrying about your indexes? Build your app!"

### Footnotes

* In a similar question [on indexes on STI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486907/will-a-compound-index-with-a-second-column-of-low-cardinality-effect-performance#answer-33973140) it was pointed out that the cost of an index is very low so when in doubt, just add it.

Answer (score 8):

Depends on how you are going to query the data.

Assuming you want to search for all of these...

- `WHERE bar_id = ?`
- `WHERE foo_id = ?`
- `WHERE bar_id = ? AND foo_id = ?`

...then you should probably go with an index on `{bar_id, foo_id}` and an index on `{foo_id}`.

While you *could* also create a third index on `{bar_id}`, the price of maintaining additional index would probably outweigh the benefit of better [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering) in the smaller index.

---

Also, how do you plan to [cover](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) your queries with indexes? Some of the alternatives, such as...

- `{foo_id, bar_id}` and `{bar_id}`
- `{foo_id, bar_id}` and `{bar_id, foo_id}`

...might cover certain kinds of queries better.

Covering is a balancing act - sometimes adding a field to an index just for covering purposes is justified, sometimes it's not. You won't know until you **measure** on realistic amounts of data.

*(Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with Ruby. This answer is purely from the database perspective.)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer Branko. This join table is necessary for the has and belongs to many relationship between the `Foo` and `Bar` models. I updated the question to further go into the typical queries generated from the Rails models.

It's starting to look like a simple index on bar_id and foo_id may be what I need. A compound on [:bar_id, :foo_id] might be useful as it will additionally prevent duplication but maybe unnecessary.