# Will a compound index with a second column of low cardinality effect performance enough that it should be used?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, indexing

## Setup

I'm using Single Table Inheritance (STI) in Rails simplified to the following:

```
class Vehicle
  belongs_to :user
end

class Car < Vehicle
end

class Plane < Vehicle
end
```

Each record in the `vehicles` table will have a `type` column set to either `'Car'` or `'Plane'` in addition to the `user_id` foreign key. It could also have additional values if more vehicle types are added, however, `type` will always have a much lower cardinality than `user_id`. Just as in real life, I expect this table to contain many more Cars.

There is a compound index on `[:user_id, :type]` (in that order) and these records are looked up by their subclasses.

## Question(s)

I believe that in the worst case of no Planes, the index will be used since `user_id` is first and the second part will essentially be ignored. In this case a single index would have a super small benefit in that it's not maintaining the compound second column.

What happens in the case where there's an equal split?

- Will the index cut the records in half and thus have a decent effect?
- Will the cost of the database maintaining a compound index over a single one (i.e. just `user_id`) exceed or negate any savings?

## Example SQL

An example ActiveRecord call would be `Car.where(user_id: 10)` which generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT `vehicles`.* FROM `vehicles` WHERE `vehicles`.`type` IN ('Car')
  AND `vehicles`.`user_id` = 10
```

Comment: I removed the Postgres tag because the syntax is MySQL.

Comment: Sorry about that. Which part makes it MySQL specific as opposed to Postgres? While I am currently using MySQL, I'm more interested in a non vendor specific answer.

Comment: The backticks are a give-away.

Comment: Haha thanks, I suppose it's been too long since I was optimizing Postgres that I forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cost of maintaining an index (single-column or multi-column) is almost always outweighed by the performance improvement when that index is used.  It is a small increment on each `INSERT`/`DELETE`, plus a cost if changing the value of an indexed field via `UPDATE`.  (The `UPDATE` case is rare.)  So, don't worry about the cost of "maintaining a compound index".

```
WHERE `vehicles`.`type` IN ('Car')
  AND `vehicles`.`user_id` = 10
```

needs `INDEX(user_id, type)`.

The optimizer will

1. discover that that index is a possible candidate,
2. check some statistics, then
3. either use the index, or decide the cardinality is poor and simply scan the table.

Include the index; don't worry about it.

I ordered the fields that way, not `(type, user_id)` based on your `IN`, which implies that you might sometimes have multiple values for `type`.

If all rows in the table have `type = 'Car'`, no problem.  Everything I have said still applies.  The waste of including the unnecessary `type` is insignificant.

It is better to have all "=" column(s) first in an index, then at most one other field.  [*Further discussion here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).