# Indexes on join tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design, database-indexes

When searching on Google for *join table indexes*, I got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790518/best-sql-indexes-for-join-table).

Now, I believe that it is giving some false information in the accepted answer, or I do not understand how everything works.
Given the following tables (running on PostGreSQL 9.4):

```sql
CREATE TABLE "albums" ("album_id" serial PRIMARY KEY, "album_name" text)
CREATE TABLE "artists" ("artist_id" serial PRIMARY KEY, "artist_name" text)
CREATE TABLE "albums_artists" ("album_id" integer REFERENCES "albums", "artist_id" integer REFERENCES "artists")
```

I was trying to replicate the scenario from the question mentioned above, by creating first an index on both of the columns of the *albums_artists* table and then one index for each column (without keeping the index on both columns).

I would have been expecting very different results when using the EXPLAIN command for a normal, traditional select like the following one:

```sql
SELECT "artists".* FROM "test"."artists"
    INNER JOIN "test"."albums_artists" ON ("albums_artists"."artist_id" = "artists"."artist_id")
    WHERE ("albums_artists"."album_id" = 1)
```

However, when actually running explain on it, I get exactly the same result for each of the cases (with one index on each column vs. one index on both columns).

I've been reading the documentation on PostGreSQL about indexing and it doesn't make any sense on the results that I am getting:

```
Hash Join  (cost=15.05..42.07 rows=11 width=36) (actual time=0.024..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (artists.artist_id = albums_artists.artist_id)
  ->  Seq Scan on artists  (cost=0.00..22.30 rows=1230 width=36) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=14.91..14.91 rows=11 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on albums_artists  (cost=4.24..14.91 rows=11 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (album_id = 1)
              Heap Blocks: exact=1
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on albums_artists_album_id_index  (cost=0.00..4.24 rows=11 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (album_id = 1)
```

I would expect to not get an Index scan at the last step when using an index composed by 2 different columns (since I am only using one of them in the *WHERE* clause).

I was about to open a bug in an ORM library that adds one index for both columns for join tables, but now I am not so sure. Can anyone help me understand why is the behavior similar in the two cases and what would actually be the difference, if there is any?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- add a NOT NULL constraint on the key columns (a tuple with NULLs would make no sense here)
- add a PRIMARY KEY (forcing a UNIQUE index on the two keyfields)
- As a suport for FK lookups : add a compound index for the PK fields *in reversed order*
- after creating/adding PKs and indexes, you may want to ANALYZE the table (only key columns have statistics)

---

```
CREATE TABLE albums_artists
    ( album_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES albums (album_id)
    , artist_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES artists (artist_id)
    , PRIMARY KEY (album_id, artist_id)
    );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON albums_artists (artist_id, album_id);
```

---

The reason behind the observed behaviour is the fact that the planner/optimiser is *information based*, driven by heuristics. Without any information about the fraction of rows that will actually be needed *given the conditions*, or the fraction of rows that actually maches (in case of a JOIN), the planner makes a guess: (for example: 10% for a range query). For a small query, a hash join will always be a winning scenario, it does imply fetching all tuples from both tables, but the join itself is very efficient.

For columns that are part of a key or index, statistics will be collected, so the planner can make more realistic estimates about the amount of rows involved. Ald that will often result in an indexed plan, since that could need fewer pages to be fetched.

Foreign keys are a very special case; since the planner will **know** that **all** the values from the referring table will be present in the referred table. (that is 100%, assuming NOT NULL)

Comment: Why have a primary key and a reversed index for the same two columns? Can't either be used if both columns are mentioned in a `WHERE` clause?